# Android/Java - Test if date was last month

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I am working on an app where I store some information between each use, this data essentially boils down to counting the number of times an event has happened today, this week, this month and in the apps lifetime. I store this data in 4 distinct counters I can load/save using SharedPreferences.

Alongside the data I store the "last run time" of the app as a date, my plan was that during load time I will load in the counters then test the stored date against today's date to determine which counters need to be cleared.

Sounds simple right!

After pulling my hair out for a while and going backward and forwards through the Calendar documentation I think I understand them enough to come up with the following:

```
    Calendar last = Calendar.getInstance();
    last.setTimeInMillis(lastDate);

    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    today.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);

    if ( !last.after(today) )
    {
                     today = 0;
    }

    today.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, -1);
    today.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);

    if ( !last.after(today) )
    {
                     today = 0;
                     week = 0;
    }

    today = Calendar.getInstance();
    today.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
    today.set(Calendar.DATE, today.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));

    if ( !last.after(today) )
    {
                     today = 0;
                     week = 0;
                     month = 0;
    }
```

I think this should be fine, however the issue I have is testing, testing today is easy, however testing the month logic would require either waiting a month, or writing a test case which uses the Calendar API to simulate an old date, however I can't write the test case if my assumptions on how the API works was wrong in the first place!

Therefore, after a large wall of text my question is... does the above block of code look sane, or have I completely mis-understood working with dates in Java?

Thanks!

### Edit:

Second pass at the code:

Does this look any more sensible? If I am understanding things correctly I am now attempting to compare the end of the date that was last saved with the very start of today, this week and this month.

```
Calendar last = Calendar.getInstance();
    last.setTimeInMillis(lastDate);

    last.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, last.getActualMaximum(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    last.set(Calendar.MINUTE, last.getActualMaximum(Calendar.MINUTE));
    last.set(Calendar.SECOND, last.getActualMaximum(Calendar.SECOND));
    last.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, last.getActualMaximum(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

    Calendar todayStart = Calendar.getInstance();
    todayStart.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, todayStart.getActualMinimum(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    todayStart.set(Calendar.MINUTE, todayStart.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MINUTE));
    todayStart.set(Calendar.SECOND, todayStart.getActualMinimum(Calendar.SECOND));
    todayStart.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, todayStart.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

    // If the last recorded date was before the absolute minimum of today
    if ( last.before(todayStart) )
    {
        todayCount = 0;
    }

    Calendar thisWeekStart = Calendar.getInstance();
    thisWeekStart.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, thisWeekStart.getActualMinimum(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    thisWeekStart.set(Calendar.MINUTE, thisWeekStart.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MINUTE));
    thisWeekStart.set(Calendar.SECOND, thisWeekStart.getActualMinimum(Calendar.SECOND));
    thisWeekStart.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, thisWeekStart.getFirstDayOfWeek());
    thisWeekStart.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, thisWeekStart.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

    // If the last date was before the absolute minimum of this week then clear
    // this week (and today, just to be on the safe side)
    if ( last.before(thisWeekStart) )
    {
        todayCount = 0;
        weekCount = 0;
    }

    Calendar thisMonthStart = Calendar.getInstance();
    thisMonthStart.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, thisMonthStart.getActualMinimum(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    thisMonthStart.set(Calendar.MINUTE, thisMonthStart.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MINUTE));
    thisMonthStart.set(Calendar.SECOND, thisMonthStart.getActualMinimum(Calendar.SECOND));
    thisMonthStart.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, thisMonthStart.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MONTH));
    thisMonthStart.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, thisMonthStart.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

    // If the last date was before the absolute minimum of this month then clear month...
    if ( !last.after(thisMonthStart) )
    {
        todayCount = 0;
        weekCount = 0;
        monthCount = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Any chance you can use Joda Time instead? It's significantly nicer - the code would be much, much easier...

Comment: Possibly, I wasn't sure about importing 3rd party APIs for use on android.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the readability challenges of using a variable called "today" and setting it to all manner of things that aren't "Today", you're not handling the time.

If it's now 3:20, and something happened at 5:00pm on Jan 31st, we probably want to still count that as happening in January?  You should max out the time related fields to the end of the day as well.

For the week thing, that can be a real mess if someone executes in a locale where Sunday is considered the first day of the week.  You may want to consider using the system's first day of week, rather than Sunday.

Also it is probably worth noting that this depends explicitly on the use of `Calendar.add()` to work properly.  `cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) -1);` is **NOT** the same thing and would be broken.

Comment: Good point on the time thing, I can rectify that, as with the first day of the week, I wasn't sure how Calendar handled this sort of thing.

As for add vs set, which should be used?

Comment: Does this look any more sensible? If I am understanding things correctly I am now attempting to compare the end of the date that was last saved with the very start of today, this week and this month.

Comment: Add should be used in this case.  Do not know what you mean by 'this' more sensible?

Comment: Sorry, I got somewhat confused with attempting to comment on here, long time browser, first time poster and all! I have added the second pass of code as an edit into my question.

Comment: Personally I would not be concerned that 23:59:59.999 would stop being the end of the day or 0:0:0.0 would stop being the start, but I guess that's a style thing :)

Answer (score 1):

You should just use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). If you do your code becomes:

```
DateTime oneMonthAgo = new DateTime().minusMonths(1);
DateTime oneWeekAgo = new DateTime().minusWeeks(1);
```

And so on... It requires no further dependencies than the JDK itself and works on Android. Hope that helps.

Comment: I will look into joda time now, although I would assume that I will hit the same difficulty, namely it could be 01/02/2013 00:00:00:001 now, and the last save could have been at 31/01/2013 23:59:59:999, in this case would a test against minusMonths(1) pass or fail, presumably if it simply knocked 1 off the month it would give me 01/01/2013 00:00:00:001 and therefore the last modified date would be after this and not before.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) on Android. (From what I've read; I don't use Android)

Yes, you should be using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Far more advanced and useful that the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date and .Calendar classes bundled with Java.

Both your question and the other answers are ignoring the crucial issue of time zone. The time zone defines the meaning of "today" and the beginning/ending of other days.

You should define in plain declarative sentences exactly what you mean by "today", "this week", and "this month". For example, "today"…

- Do you mean the last 24 hours?
- Do you mean from 00:00:00 and up to but not including 00:00:00 tomorrow, in the UTC/GMT time zone (that is, no time zone offset)?
- Do mean from the first moment of today in a given time zone (some offset from UTC) up to but not including the first moment of tomorrow in the same time zone? This may not be 24 hours because of Daylight Saving Time (DST) or other anomalies.

I'm too tired to parse your code. And I shouldn't have to. Before writing such date-time code, you should spell out in plain English what your goal is. Date-time work is surprisingly tricky, so you must be clear on your goals.

Here's some example code in Joda-Time 2.3.

Joda-Time uses the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for most defaults. This includes the definition of a week. Monday is first day, numbered 1, and Sunday is last day, numbered 7.

When focusing on a "day" with date-time objects, you may want to start with the first moment of the day. If so, call the `withTimeAtStartOfDay` method. To get end-of-day, don't. Use the Half-Open approach where you compare up to but not including the first moment of the *next* day. Explanation is found in other answers on StackOverflow.

Joda-Time offers 3 classes to handle spans of time: Period, Duration, and Interval. Check them all out. When doing comparisons, Joda-Time uses the "Half-Open" approach where the beginning is inclusive and the ending is exclusive. This makes sense when you ponder it. Search StackOverflow for more discussion.

Here's a bit of example code to get you going. I take a set of arbitrary date-time values. Then I define some spans of time as a day, week ago, and month ago. Then I count how many of the values fall into those spans.

```
String input = "2014-01-02T03:04:05Z";

DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );

java.util.List<DateTime> dateTimes = new java.util.ArrayList<DateTime>();
DateTime dateTime1 = new DateTime( input, timeZone ); // Parse the string as being in Zulu time zone (UTC). Then adjust to Montréal time.
dateTimes.add( dateTime1 );
dateTimes.add( dateTime1.plusDays( 3 ) );
dateTimes.add( dateTime1.plusWeeks( 1 ) );
dateTimes.add( dateTime1.plusMonths( 1 ) );
DateTime now = new DateTime( timeZone );
dateTimes.add( now );
dateTimes.add( now.minusDays( 1 ) );
dateTimes.add( now.minusDays( 10 ) );

// Spans of time
Interval today = new Interval( now.withTimeAtStartOfDay(), now.plusDays( 1 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay() );
Interval pastWeek = new Interval( now.minusWeeks( 1 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay(), now.plusDays( 1 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay() );
Interval pastMonth = new Interval( now.minusMonths( 1 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay(), now.plusDays( 1 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay() );

int countTotal = dateTimes.size();
int countDay = 0;
int countWeek = 0;
int countMonth = 0;
for ( DateTime dateTime : dateTimes ) {
    if ( today.contains( dateTime ) ) {
        countDay++;
    }
    if ( pastWeek.contains( dateTime ) ) {
        countWeek++;
    }
    if ( pastMonth.contains( dateTime ) ) {
        countMonth++;
    }
}
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "dateTimes: " + dateTimes );
System.out.println( "today: " + today );
System.out.println( "pastWeek: " + pastWeek );
System.out.println( "pastMonth: " + pastMonth );
System.out.println( "countTotal: " + countTotal );
System.out.println( "countDay: " + countDay );
System.out.println( "countWeek: " + countWeek );
System.out.println( "countMonth: " + countMonth );
```

When run…

```
dateTimes: [2014-01-01T22:04:05.000-05:00, 2014-01-04T22:04:05.000-05:00, 2014-01-08T22:04:05.000-05:00, 2014-02-01T22:04:05.000-05:00, 2014-03-05T07:40:25.508-05:00, 2014-03-04T07:40:25.508-05:00, 2014-02-23T07:40:25.508-05:00]
today: 2014-03-05T00:00:00.000-05:00/2014-03-06T00:00:00.000-05:00
pastWeek: 2014-02-26T00:00:00.000-05:00/2014-03-06T00:00:00.000-05:00
pastMonth: 2014-02-05T00:00:00.000-05:00/2014-03-06T00:00:00.000-05:00
countTotal: 7
countDay: 1
countWeek: 2
countMonth: 3
```